# Conditional redirects in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js

Is there a clean way to redirect only if I'm on the redirecting route and not on their child routes?

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  ...
  redirect: function(record, transition) {
    if(transition.targetName === 'index')
      this.replaceWith('index.nested');
```

When I remove the `if` the redirect fires every time I refresh a nested route of `index`.

The `Transition` class is private (don't know why I even get it here if it's private) so I shouldn't use it for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Are you saying your Index route has child routes?

Comment: This was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to use a different example say `PostsRoute` (because Index is 'special') located at `/posts` would also load `PostsIndexRoute` only for the parent where you can put your redirect code. Visits to `/posts/new`won't redirect.

Comment: Ah so it could be that because I'm using the `index` route, it gets triggered every time I refresh a nested route of index?

Comment: yes, for all child routes the parent route is also loaded (as is the template if it's present)